# 2 random page breaks in CV

Tags: page-breaking, cv

I´m quite new to lateX never had any real problems with articles, BUT this CV is killing me: upon compiling it spits out everything perfectly fine EXCEPT for two page breaks which make absolutely no sense:

The first right between the "school" section and the "work experience" sec.
This is particularly ugly since that leaves 3/4 of the page white.

The second page break is after the 6th workplace and sets 7 workplace on the next page, which leaves half the page empty.

What's up with that? What did I do wrong? (I tried `\let\clearpage\relax` without success).

See code under

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%A Few Useful Packages
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}               
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}   
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fullpage} %**
\usepackage{supertabular}           
\usepackage{titlesec}               

%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\setmainfont[
SmallCapsFont = Fontin-SmallCaps.otf,
BoldFont = Fontin-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont = Fontin-Italic.otf
]
{Fontin.otf}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}

\hyphenation{im-pre-se}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{2mm}{0.65\paperheight}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}


%--------------------BEGIN DOCUMENT----------------------
\begin{document}
\graphicspath{ {pic/} }



\pagestyle{empty} 

\font\fb=''[cmr10]'' 

%--------------------TITLE-------------
\par{\centering
        {\Huge \textsc{name}
    }\bigskip\par}
%--------------------SECTIONS-----------------------------------
%Section: Personal Data
\section{Persönliche Daten}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{RlR}
    \raggedright\textsc{birthday} & 01.01.1980 &
    \multirow{4}{*}{\hfill}\\
    \raggedright\textsc{Citizenship}   & xy \\
    \raggedright\textsc{Adresse}     &  uyz 15, 1111 city, country\\
    \raggedright\textsc{Telefon}     & +1111111111\\
    \raggedright\textsc{Email} & \href{mailto:smarties@gmail.com}{smerties@gmail.com}\\
    \raggedright\textsc{Skype} & xyz
\end{tabularx}

\section{Universität und Schulbildung}
\begin{tabular}{rl} 
 \textsc{2001 -} laufend &  \textsc{University of Hogwarts} \footnotesize{Bachelorstudium sourcery}\\
\textsc{2011} & \textsc{Paper:} \footnotesize{"A General Overview of how to burn whiches} \\ 
\textsc{2011} & \textsc{30 hous of quiddich} \footnotesize{in the university team top level}\\


\textsc{2000 - 2004} & \textsc{Highschool}, London\\
            & \hyperlink{thesentence}{A-level}: average 1,0 \footnotesize{Fachbereichsarbeit}\\ 
\textsc{2000 - 2004} & \textsc{school}, Hometown\\

\textsc{2000 - 2004} & \textsc{school}, Hometown
\end{tabular}


\section{working experience}
\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
 \textsc{10.2015 -} laufend & \textsc{1 Workplace} City, Country \\
                        &\emph{Wizard}\\
                        &\footnotesize{Head magician}
                        \\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

 \textsc{01.2001-01.2001} & \textsc{2 Workplace}, City \\                             
                            &\emph{Wizard}\\
                            &\footnotesize{Head magician} \\
                            \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

\textsc{01.2001-01.2001}  & \textsc{3 Workplace}, City\\
                            & \emph{Wizard}\\
                            &\footnotesize{Head magician}\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\


\textsc{01.2001-01.2001}   & \textsc{4 Workplace}, City\\
                        &\emph{Wizard}\\
                        &\footnotesize{doing mostly magic on a professional level}\\
                        \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\

\textsc{01.2001-01.2001}    & \textsc{5 Workplace}, City, Country \\
                            &\emph{Wizard}\\
                            &\footnotesize{doing mostly magic on a professional level}\\
                            \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\

\textsc{01.2001-01.2001}    & \textsc{6 Workplace}, City, Country\\
                            &\emph{Wizard}\\
                            &\footnotesize{doing magic}\\
                            \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
                                                        \end{tabular}

                            \begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}

\textsc{01.2001-01.2001}  & \textsc{7 Workplace}, City\\
                            &\emph{Wizard}\\
                            &\footnotesize{doing mostly magic on a professional level}\\
                            \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\           

\textsc{01.2001-01.2001}    & \textsc{8 Workplace}, City, Country\\
                            &\emph{Wizard}\\
                            &\footnotesize{doing mostly magic on a professional level}\\
                            \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\

\textsc{01.2001-01.2001}  & \textsc{9 Workplace}, City, Country\\
                          &\emph{Wizard}\\
                          &\footnotesize{doing mostly magic on a professional level}\\

                        \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
\textsc{01.2001-01.2001}    & \textsc{10 Workplace}, City, Country \\
                            &\emph{Wizard}\\
                            &\footnotesize{doing mostly magic on a professional level}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
    \textsc{01.2001-01.2001} & \textsc{11 Workplace}, City\\
                            &\emph{internship as Wizard}\\
                            &\footnotesize{learning basics of magic}
\end{tabular}

%Section: Languages
\section{Languages}
\begin{tabular}{rl}

\raggedright\textsc{Language:}\\&\footnotesize{Native}\\
\raggedright\textsc{Extra:}\\&\footnotesize{extremely good cant stop talking (C2 )}\\
\raggedright\textsc{Esperanto:}\\&\footnotesize{extremely good cant stop talking (C2 )}\\
\raggedright\textsc{Latin:}\\&\footnotesize{extremely good cant stop talking (C2 )}\\
\raggedright\textsc{Greek:}\\&\footnotesize{extremely good cant stop talking (C2 )}
\end{tabular}

\section{extra ordinarities}
\begin{itemize}

  \item I can use a computer:\\  \textsc{turn it on}, turn it off, \textsc{install firefox}, \textsc{protonmail}, \textsc{i can type}, \textsc{read}, \textsc{OpenOffice}, \textsc{write}, {\fb \LaTeX}\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont=Fontin-SmallCaps.otf]{Fontin.otf}
  \item Driverslicence Nimbus 2000


\end{itemize}

\section{Interests}
Wizardry, and Mikado\\


\end{document}
```

Comment: size commands do not take an argument  so `\footnotesize doing...` not `\footnotesize{doing...}`

Comment: `\raggedright` does nothing in an `l` column

Comment: `Wizardry, and Mikado\\ ` never end a paragraph with `\\ ` (makes underfull hbox 10000 warning)

Comment: It's impossible to see where your code page breaks as I don't have the font and it uses images that are not generally available. Can you edit the example so that it can be run just using a standard tex distribution, but still shows your issue

Comment: Out of topic: I don't think it's your real email, but if so be careful: you have a typo in `\href{mailto:smarties@gmail.com}{smerties@gmail.com}` (the link is different from the displayed email address). I'd suggest you creating a macro like `\newcommand{\email}[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{#1}}` to be sure to avoid such issue: you don't input twice the same information (what doubles your change of making a typo).

Comment: `\raggedright\textsc{Language:}\\` and each of teh following liens generates the error `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.`  delete the `\raggedright` and the `\\ `

Comment: isnt a real mail - hm i just filled in what the template said - and there it was twice...

Thanks

Comment: i put in the \raggedright\textsc{Language:}\ because it made a huge difference on the output - it kept language and skill in one line and still produced a pdf -
Also the sizes of the language changed - it just looked better, even if it was unorthodox.

Comment: @krokkebolle it's not unorthodox, it's completely wrong:-)

Comment: Why don't you use longtable instead of tabular?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yup, ture wrong, wrong, wrong, just as hard as wizardry :-)

Comment: @krokkebolle tex's recovery from errors is designed to allow syntax checking of more of the document, it isn't designed to produce sensible pdf. after an error it really isn't worth even looking at the pdf, even if it looks plausible any typeset output is essentially accidental unplanned error recovery.

Comment: This seems to be based on Friggeri CV? Terrible class. Many design faults. Not recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two forced page breaks (a `\clearpage` and a `\newpage`) and had forced the page size to be about half the physical page, that combined with the fact that `tabular` do not break so if it does not fit the whole table has to go to the next page.

However your code was producing errors from misuse of `\\` and warnings If I fix those and delete the references to fonts and images that I don't hav ethen I get

[image]

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%A Few Useful Packages
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}               
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}   
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fullpage} %**
\usepackage{supertabular}           
\usepackage{titlesec}               

%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}



\usepackage{pdfpages}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}

\hyphenation{im-pre-se}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
%\textblockorigin{2mm}{0.65\paperheight}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}


%--------------------BEGIN DOCUMENT----------------------
\begin{document}
\graphicspath{ {pic/} }



\pagestyle{empty} 

\font\fb=''[cmr10]'' 

%--------------------TITLE-------------
\par{\centering
        {\Huge \textsc{name}
    }\bigskip\par}
%--------------------SECTIONS-----------------------------------
%Section: Personal Data
\section{Persönliche Daten}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{RlR}
    \raggedright\textsc{birthday} & 01.01.1980 &
    \multirow{4}{*}{\hfill\includegraphics[width=0.13\textwidth]{example-image}}\\
    \raggedright\textsc{Citizenship}   & xy \\
    \raggedright\textsc{Adresse}     &  uyz 15, 1111 city, country\\
    \raggedright\textsc{Telefon}     & +1111111111\\
    \raggedright\textsc{Email} & \href{mailto:smarties@gmail.com}{smerties@gmail.com}\\
    \raggedright\textsc{Skype} & xyz
\end{tabularx}

\section{Universität und Schulbildung}
\begin{tabular}{rl} 
 \textsc{2001 -} laufend &  \textsc{University of Hogwarts} \footnotesize{Bachelorstudium sourcery}\\
\textsc{2011} & \textsc{Paper:} \footnotesize{"A General Overview of how to burn whiches} \\ 
\textsc{2011} & \textsc{30 hous of quiddich} \footnotesize{in the university team top level}\\


\textsc{2000 - 2004} & \textsc{Highschool}, London\\
            & \hyperlink{thesentence}{A-level}: average 1,0 \footnotesize{Fachbereichsarbeit}\\ 
\textsc{2000 - 2004} & \textsc{school}, Hometown\\

\textsc{2000 - 2004} & \textsc{school}, Hometown
\end{tabular}


\section{working experience}
\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
 \textsc{10.2015 -} laufend & \textsc{1 Workplace} City, Country \\
                        &\emph{Wizard}\\
                        &\footnotesize{Head magician}
                        \\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

 \textsc{01.2001-01.2001} & \textsc{2 Workplace}, City \\                             
                            &\emph{Wizard}\\
                            &\footnotesize{Head magician} \\
                            \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

\textsc{01.2001-01.2001}  & \textsc{3 Workplace}, City\\
                            & \emph{Wizard}\\
                            &\footnotesize{Head magician}\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\


\textsc{01.2001-01.2001}   & \textsc{4 Workplace}, City\\
                        &\emph{Wizard}\\
                        &\footnotesize{doing mostly magic on a professional level}\\
                        \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\

\textsc{01.2001-01.2001}    & \textsc{5 Workplace}, City, Country \\
                            &\emph{Wizard}\\
                            &\footnotesize{doing mostly magic on a professional level}\\
                            \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\

\textsc{01.2001-01.2001}    & \textsc{6 Workplace}, City, Country\\
                            &\emph{Wizard}\\
                            &\footnotesize{doing magic}\\
                            \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
                                                        \end{tabular}

                            \begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}

\textsc{01.2001-01.2001}  & \textsc{7 Workplace}, City\\
                            &\emph{Wizard}\\
                            &\footnotesize{doing mostly magic on a professional level}\\
                            \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\           

\textsc{01.2001-01.2001}    & \textsc{8 Workplace}, City, Country\\
                            &\emph{Wizard}\\
                            &\footnotesize{doing mostly magic on a professional level}\\
                            \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\

\textsc{01.2001-01.2001}  & \textsc{9 Workplace}, City, Country\\
                          &\emph{Wizard}\\
                          &\footnotesize{doing mostly magic on a professional level}\\

                        \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
\textsc{01.2001-01.2001}    & \textsc{10 Workplace}, City, Country \\
                            &\emph{Wizard}\\
                            &\footnotesize{doing mostly magic on a professional level}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
    \textsc{01.2001-01.2001} & \textsc{11 Workplace}, City\\
                            &\emph{internship as Wizard}\\
                            &\footnotesize{learning basics of magic}
\end{tabular}

%Section: Languages
\section{Languages}
\begin{tabular}{rl}

\textsc{Language:}&\footnotesize{Native}\\
\textsc{Extra:}&\footnotesize{extremely good cant stop talking (C2 )}\\
\textsc{Esperanto:}&\footnotesize{extremely good cant stop talking (C2 )}\\
\textsc{Latin:}&\footnotesize{extremely good cant stop talking (C2 )}\\
\textsc{Greek:}&\footnotesize{extremely good cant stop talking (C2 )}
\end{tabular}

\section{extra ordinarities}
\begin{itemize}

  \item I can use a computer:\\  \textsc{turn it on}, turn it off, \textsc{install firefox}, \textsc{protonmail}, \textsc{i can type}, \textsc{read}, \textsc{OpenOffice}, \textsc{write}, {\fb \LaTeX}
  \item Driverslicence Nimbus 2000


\end{itemize}

\section{Interests}
Wizardry, and Mikado


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks that looks good, but the bottom of page one is still quite long... I´ll follow your advice

Comment: @krokkebolle as I say above, because you have chosen to use a tabular no page breaking is possible except at that point where you have stopped and restarted the table.  It is not ideal markup really.

Comment: now i removed the:
-  \footnotesize {}´s
- raggedrights and replaced by {l l} columns
- \\ at the end of each paragraph
- > what made the trick in the end was of course as you said the tabular: i just ended it at an estimated point (were it should fit) and restarted it for the other "workplaces" that made the trick!

Thanks a lot- you truly saved my career in wizardry :-)

Answer (score 0):

Between workplace 6 and workplace 7, you terminate the tabular, issue a `\newpage` and start another tabular. I think that explains the second break.

Comment: nope ;) was a typo - i took it in and out to see if it would add an extra page (which it did not) just forgot to remove it before i copied it from mine...

Comment: That's because terminating the tabular introduced a page break. \newpage will not add another page break on top of that one.